# How to get selective column in spring boot JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring boot.

I have two entities Invite and User.

```
@Entity
public class Invite {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email_id;
    private String mobile;
    private String pincode;
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private Date created_on;
    private Date updated_on;
 
    //gettes and setters
}


@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @OneToOne
    private Invite invite;
    private String firstName;
    private String LastName;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    private Date created_on;
    private Date updated_on;

    // getters and setters

}
```

I want the following data

```
+---------+---------------------------------------------+
|  id     |   firstName    email_id         mobile      |
+-------------------+------------+----------------------+
|         |         |            |                      |
| 1       |Ram      | s@mail.com |      1111111111      |
|         |         |            |                      |
+---------+---------+------------+----------------------+
```

So I have created the below query in UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    
    @Query("select u.id,u.firstName,i.email_id, i.mobile from User u inner join u.invite i")
    public List<User> getUserDetails();
}
```

So I am getting the below error -

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.example.jpa.JPA.entity.User] for value
```

I know it's because the return value is of type Object and I am trying to get it into user.

Could you please give me a way to get any data without creating extra DTO classes or interface?

Comment: And adding to this, you need to understand the problem is not related to Spring Boot. It is a JPA related question which can be solved using Jpa Query, or Data Jpa abstractions of @Query and Query Projection interface and classes. Correcting the the tags

Answer (score 5):

Its great you already know what the issue is.

```java
@Query("select u.id,u.firstName,i.email_id, i.mobile from User u inner join u.invite i")
List<User> getUserDetails();
```

You are selecting a few columns but asking Data-Jpa to return you back with the a List of **User** Objects.

**So you need to understand first, what JPA specification says about using JPQL.**

- `select u from User u where u.id = :id` -> this returns a List of `User` type Objects
  This query in native is : `SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID = "{whatever value you passed}";`
- `select u.username from User u where u.id = :id"` -> this returns just the username, which lets say is a String type. So the return object type is of the String type in case you using [TypedQuery](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#jpql-api) or Object is returned in case you using [Query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#jpql-api) . The corresponding SQL generated is `SELECT u.USERNAME FROM USER u WHERE u.id = {id}`
- `select u.id, u.username from User u where u.id = :id` -> this returns Object[]. This is when you need the DTO projection to map it to a proper Type of what you want.

With native JPA implementations you can use [DTO Projection](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) or [Query Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

I mostly use DTO Projection from JPA spec ad not use Query Projection, so I am giving an example of DTO projection, but above documents if gone through gives a good reference how to work with each abstraction/feature.

1. Define a class to represent the DTO and package I am taking into consideration: com.example. *Package name is important since you need the full class name for reference in JPQL*

```java
package com.example;


class UserDTO {
 int id;
 String firstName,
 String email_id;
 String mobile;

 //All args constructor is needed and madatory
public User(int id, String firstName, String email_id, String mobile) {
 // assignments
}
  // getters and setters
}
```

In the Repository:

```java
@Query("select new com.example.UserDTO(u.id,u.firstName,i.email_id, i.mobile) from User u inner join u.invite i")
List<UserDTO> getUserDetails();
```

The most important thing being : ***new fully-qualifed-classname(all columns you are fetching)***

This is how you use DTO projection with JPQL and Data Jpa Repository.

Comment: Thank you. Can we make use of Tuple in the same way.

Comment: Yes, check the link I shared. [Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/blog/) is one of the top contributors to Hibernate and going through his blogs is one of the best things you can do. You should also go through the [JPA spec](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) and the [Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html)

Comment: Can you please show me the same example using Tuple

Comment: Can you please check this [link](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) I shared above. There is an example with DTO and also Tuple

Answer (score 1):

Write a constructor in `User` class for your selective column and use in query. Make sure you are also using a constructor in `Invite` class for `email_id` and `mobile` and use it inside constructor in User.

```
@Query("select new com.example.jpa.JPA.entity.User(u.id,u.firstName,i.email_id, i.mobile) from User u inner join u.invite i")
public List<User> getUserDetails();
```

Use this constructor in User and Invite class

```
public User(int id, String firstName, String email_id, String mobile) {
 // assign id and firstName
 // call invite class constuctor 
}

public Invite(String email_id, String mobile) {
 // assign email_id and mobile
}
```

Comment: You missed the keyword _new_

Comment: `select new com.example.jpa.JPA.entity.User(u.id, new com.example.userDefinedObject(u.firstName) from ...` Is this valid statement?

Comment: @JavaLearner Nope, rather call the inner constructor inside the User constructor

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have selected fields in query result or customize query result, you can simply use `jpa Projection`. create an interface with related property method

Comment: OP said _get any data without creating extra DTO classes or interface_

Answer (score -1):

try this ..this work for me :
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy

this is to be added in application.properties